# use drupal_add_js for file outside drupal dir

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a js file thats outside my drupal installation dir, but keep it relative to that dir.

```
mysite
  |-- drupal
  |-- dirWithJsFile
      |-- thisfile.js
```

i have already tried things like

```
/../dirWithJsFile/thisfile.js
../dirWithJsFile/thisfile.js
```

but add_js seems not be able to go outside the drupal dir or is there an option i must set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript file you want to add is not inside your drupal installation so you need to add it the same way you would do it with an external file:

```
drupal_add_js('http://yourdomain.com/dirWithJsFile/thisfile.js', 'external');
```

See [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

In D6, no dice, but in D7, you could fudge it with setting $options to external and then using the full sitename and path to the file.

Comment: I use D7, but the site url directs to the drupal directory

Comment: well, everything is relative to the webroot, so your file would need to be under there anyway for security reasons.  otherwise, someone could do www.mysite.com/etc/passwd (as an example to date myself)